# ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle

Can you help me know what maybe the error in my sql?ORA-00936: I'm having missing expressionerror but I cannot find the error.

```
CREATE TYPE T_ordRef AS OBJECT (
   Ordi REF T_Ordinateur
);
CREATE TYPE T_ordRefs AS TABLE OF REF T_ordRef ;

INSERT INTO THE (SELECT INSTALLESUR FROM LOGICIEL WHERE NUMERO='1')
VALUES (T_ORDREFS( T_ORDREF(SELECT REF(v) 
FROM ORDINATEUR v WHERE v.NUMSERIE='1') ));
```

Error:

> Erreur à la ligne de commande : 81, colonne : 34 Rapport d'erreur :
>   Erreur SQL : ORA-00936: missing expression
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: Your insert is completely wrong. What are your trying to achieve with that?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a / after the lines that create the types:

```
CREATE TYPE T_ordRef AS OBJECT ( Ordi REF T_Ordinateur );
/  -- important!

CREATE TYPE T_ordRefs AS TABLE OF REF T_ordRef ;
/  -- important!
```

Additionally, your `insert into` is completely wrong, as you are not allowed to have a select in the part that is reserved for the column names.
Unfortunately, I can't correct it, because I don't even understand what it is supposed to do.

Comment: The `/` is not necessary at all because there is already a `;`. In fact using `;` **and** `/` is wrong because the `/` executes whatever is in the buffer of SQL*Plus. So your example would actually run the `CREATE TYPE` statements twice.

Comment: thank you Daniel Hilgarth
i have table name "ORDINATEUR" this table have column for name "Leslogiciels" (SOFTWARE in this PC) ,
and another table name LOGICIEL (SOFTWARE) have column this column type "T_ordRefs" : i wana add REF from table ORDINATEUR where table ID "ORDINATEUR" = ID "LOGICIEL"

i hope u understand what i supposed i wanna do

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I believe you're wrong about that.  In the case of code objects, the semicolon is part of the object definition, so does not serve to execute the code, therefore the slash is necessary.  If you enter simply the first line terminated with a semicolon, SQL*Plus keeps prompting for more input: `SQL> create type my_type as object( x number );
  2  /

Type created.
`

Comment: @DaveCosta: hmm, seems that `CREATE TYPE` is indeed treated differently. I did't expect it to be treated like "procedure code" as it is a regular "object". A `CREATE VIEW` will certainly show the behaviour I was talking about. Thanks for the clarification.